# Combining multiple Docker images to create build environment

Tags: docker

I am the developer of a software product ([NJOY](https://NJOY.github.io)) with build requirements of:

- CMake 3.2
- Python 3.4
- gcc 6.2 or clang 3.9
- gfortran 5.3+

In reading about Docker, it seems that I should be able to create an image with just these components so that I can compile my code and use it. Much of the documentation is written with the implication that one wants to create a scalable web architecture and thus, doesn’t appear to be applicable to compiled applications like what I’m trying to do. I know it is applicable, I just can’t seem to figure out what to do.

I’m struggling with separating the Docker concept from a Virtual Machine; I can only conceive of compiling my code in an environment that contains an entire OS instead of just the necessary components. I’ve begun a Docker image by starting with an Ubuntu image. This seems to work just fine, but I get the feeling that I’m overly complicating things.

I’ve seen a [Docker image for gcc](https://hub.docker.com/_/gcc/); I’d like to combine it with CMake and Python into an image that we can use. Is this even possible?

> What is the right way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining docker images is not available. Docker images are chained. You start from a base images and you then install additional tools that you want to add on top of the base image.

For instance, you can start from the gcc image and build on it by creating a Dockerfile. Your Dockerfile might look something like:

```
FROM gcc:latest

# install cmake
RUN apt-get install cmake

# Install python 
RUN apt-get install python
```

Then you build this dockerfile to create the Docker image. This will give you an image that contains gcc, cmake and python.